# iOS App Login integration with Facebook with Xcode 11.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have an iOS template APP which has a login page once we run the app. (It has Email login and Facebook Login)

I haven't setup the API or anything yet. There is a file called ApiConfig.h in the project folder containing following code. I think its the location of REST APIs. I have no clue how to configure this.

Is this Objective-C? Is it Swift? How Can I import my API keys? Is this workable with Firebase?

```
#ifndef ApiConfig_h
#define ApiConfig_h

#define     PH_FAIL_STATE               400

#define     PH_API_BASE_URL             @"//yourwebsite.com/AppName/public/api/v1/"
#define     PH_API_BASE_ITEM_FILE_URL   @"//yourwebsite.com/AppName/public/uploads/item/"
#define     PH_API_BASE_USER_FILE_URL   @"//yourwebsite.com/AppName/public/uploads/user/"
```

I also get this error in Xcode once I click on Facebook Login Button. On the app i get the error: The server with specific name could not be found.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002b5c6f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <02829F4A-5D3B-4E11-A658-6AA442C445A0>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <02829F4A-5D3B-4E11-A658-6AA442C445A0>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=//yourwebsite.com/AppName/api/v1/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=//yourwebsite.com/AppName/public/api/v1/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question seems to be raising more questions. Please be specific on what's the problem so that we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply..The problem is, the Facebook login button is not working. And Im pretty sure that this: PH_API_BASE_URL
is responsible for this login process..I have no idea to configure this part..

Comment: Your url is invalid when going to be hit. @user1575945

Comment: Have you try to debug your code? , If answer is yes so must have found something more specific, Please add that information so other can help you in any way.